# DNS set up: Can I host different files in different servers?

Tags: dns

Let's say this is my domain: http://www.example.com.

And I have two servers available for it, one is from godaddy, one is from heroku.

Now I want to set up the DNS such that I can host all the images and xml files in godaddy (does not support SSL) and the PHP and HTML in heroku would be able to use them (via HTTPS, so that there won't be this warning: *page includes other resources which are not secure.*).

Is it possible? How should I configure the DNS?

I am not very experienced with DNS and working with servers so it would be great if anyone can teach me how this is done, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One DNS record **can not** point to two different servers at the same time.
2. Since you are looking to use two different servers for for you content hosting I would suggest having **subdomains** like `images.example.com` and `XML.example.com`.
3. You just need to add extra **A records** for your sub domains from the control panel of your name server.

Update:

- The browser tries to verify the digital signature of certification authority (e.g.verisign) on your SSL certificate using the CAs digital certificate.
- If you have not obtained an SSL certificate from a trusted certification authority (CA) the
  browser will throw up the error. If you really want to use HTTPS You need to have an authentic digital certificate.

Comment: Can the content (IMG&XML) hosted in my subdomain by a do-not-support-SSL server (godaddy) be accessed via HTTPS when users access the content (HTML&PHP) hosted by a support-SSL server (heroku) ?

Answer (score 1):

i do not think that a domain can be mapped to 2 different servers (IP), what you can do is that you can create a sub domain like files.example.com on godady and upload all the images and xml files there and set the main domain example.com at heroku.

Comment: Can the content (IMG&XML) hosted in my subdomain by a do-not-support-SSL server (godaddy) be accessed via HTTPS when users access the content (HTML&PHP) hosted by a support-SSL server (heroku) ?

Comment: Well if your php and html files are hosted on heroku which supports SSL, should be able to access files from non SSL supported host,however there might be problem for JavaScript to access content from another domain (cross domain issue).